# NumberFormatException in Java project

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I'm trying to retrieve details of a single patient record among the records which I had previously added in my Oracle 10g database, using input as phone number attribute. i.e. I want to get details on a single record using its phone no. attribute.

But I get a `NumberFormatException` when I click the button. The `actionPerformed` for that button is here:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try{  
        Connection con = null;
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","passw");  

        String number = jTextField1.getText().trim(); /fetching the input here*/

        int phone = Integer.parseInt(number);/*converting string to integer*/


        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE pphone==?");

                    ps.setInt(1,phone);

        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
                    jLabel16.setText("Fetching details, please wait");
                    jLabel2.setText(rs.getString("pid"));
                    jLabel3.setText(rs.getString("pname"));
                    jLabel4.setText(rs.getString("page"));
                    jLabel5.setText(rs.getString("psex"));
                    jLabel6.setText(rs.getString("pphone"));
                    jLabel7.setText(rs.getString("paddress"));
                    jLabel8.setText(rs.getString("pfamilymembers"));
                    jLabel16.setText("Details Fetched Successfully");
}                                        
catch(Exception e){
showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

I have tried answers from previous threads but they didn't help.

How can I avoid or handle this exception?

Comment: Print the stack trace of the exception. That will tell you where the exception is thrown, and what its message is. Then read it, and fix your code accordingly.

Comment: @Natarajan on which line is it throwing error?

Comment: I get the exception here...int phone = Integer.parseInt(number); I used to get this exception in the output pane in netbeans. Now I get the exception on the optionpane dialog when I run the Jframe.

Comment: @Natarajan and what is the string value you are trying to convert to integer value?

Comment: @Natarajan Is it like (string a = " FOUR") or something ???

Comment: @Natarajan have you handled your code with try/catch block.?

Comment: @TusharSharma I enter a string input like ex : "9854713254". I use catch expression to show the exception, Any suggestions to handle this exception?

Comment: @Natarajan R are you sure you are getting value in number variable ?? Make sure it is not getting nil .

Comment: @TusharSharma I got it now... using   String number = String.valueOf(getText.jTextField1); to get the value in the "String" variable not int. The query runs properly now :)

Comment: @Natarajan R Kudos for the success..:)

Answer (score 0):

is there any chance your input is greater than [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) if so you can use `Long.parseLong("String")`

Answer (score 0):

you can't avoid it. the value is important for the last code after

```
int phone = Integer.parseInt(number);/*converting string to integer*/
```

you should check/validate input values before passing it in the context.

```
int phone = -1
if (!String.isEmpty(number))
  //proceed
  try {
      phone = Integer.parseInt(number);/*converting string to integer*/
      ....
  } catch (NumberFormatException e){
    throw new Exception("Number is invalid", e);
  }
else
  throw new Exception ("Number is empty");
```

Answer (score 0):

The code runs successfully now,
I passed the jTextField value into the "String" variable instead of int using "valueOf(int)" method

```
String number = String.valueOf(getText.jTextField1);
```